# Hand Cursor is not working in the firefox browser

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, mouse-cursor

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Question</title>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function MouseOverHand(ID)
{
  var Cursor='hand';
  var ID=ID;
  if (!document.all){ Cursor='pointer'; }
  document.getElementById(ID).style.cursor=Cursor;      
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function MouseOverHelp(ID)
{
  var Cursor='help';
  var ID=ID;
  if (!document.all){ Cursor='pointer'; }
  document.getElementById(ID).style.cursor=Cursor;      
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<label id="Hand" onmouseover="MouseOverHand('Hand');" > Hand </label><br/><br/>
<label id="Help" onmouseover="MouseOverHelp('Help');" > Help </label>
</body>

</html>
```

The above html is used to take mouse cursor in the mouse over of labels. Here, "Hand" and "help" cursor is working fine in Internet Explorer, but it's not working in Firefox and other browsers.

Comment: i think you meant to tag this as javascript (not java)

Comment: Um, JavaScript is really unnecessary in this situation. I'd recommend you use a CSS solution.

Comment: @mportiz08: Yea, I've re-tagged for the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need `var Cursor` if you can specify `help` or `hand` directly like so

```
document.getElementById(ID).style.cursor='hand';
```

and

```
document.getElementById(ID).style.cursor='help';
```

please check [working example](http://jsbin.com/edura) and take a look at the html source code

Answer (score 1):

Simpler version, works on 'all' browsers:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function MouseOverPointer(obj) //obj is the triggering element
{
    if(obj.id=='Help')
        obj.style.cursor = "help";
    else if(obj.id=='Hand')
        obj.style.cursor = "pointer";
}
</script>

<label id="Hand" onmouseover="MouseOverPointer(this);" > Hand </label><br/><br/>
<label id="Help" onmouseover="MouseOverPointer(this);" > Help </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

"Hand" does not work in Firefox.  Try "[pointer](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_cursor.asp)".  "help", however, should work -- try applying the style in a more direct way than via JS.